# parsing wikipedia categories

Tags: php, json, wikipedia

I am attempting to parse wikipedia categories with the following URL:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&cllimit=max&prop=categories&titles=Albert%20Einstein

...where "albert einstein" is any wikipedia page

The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to parse without hard coding the pageid, which is variable (in this case "736" - which only works for this page).

Note: I just started learning JSON today, so this may be an easy one.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = str_replace('_',' ',$page);

$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&format=json&cllimit=max&prop=categories&titles='.$page;

echo $url;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TestScript");

$c = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($c);

$content = $json->{'query'}->{'pages'}->{'736'}->{'categories'};

print_r ($content);
```

Comment: what are you taking your target pages from? you want random? want to get whole wiki? what is the key for the pageid you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would assume there could, at least in theory, be multiple pages, so why not:

```
foreach ($json->{'query'}->{'pages'} as $page) {
    print_r ($page->{'categories'});
}
```